# Unable to generate key hashes for my android application

Tags: facebook, ssl, key

I am trying to generate a development key for my application using the link:

> https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1561810364100201/?platform=android

I have installed Open-SSL 0.9.8[x64] on my system, performed the restart as said but still i get the following error on Dos-prompt:

**openssl is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**"

I must tell you that this is the command that i am giving :

```html
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

My OpenSSL is installed in : C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.exe

My system configuration: 
OS - Win 8.1[x64]

I tried no of links given here on stack-overflow but none seemed to work for me.

Please guide me as to where am I doing it wrong.

Response awaited.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```